# Iterating over key-value arrays in Twig?

Tags: twig, symfony, symfony-3.1

I'm (finally) switching my site from Drupal7 to Symfony3.

I'm working on migrating my layout to .twig.

I've got a question about loops and key-value arrays.

I've configured a k/v array

```
{% set test = {
        sec1: {
            title:   "title 1",
            content: "content 1"
        },
        sec2: {
            title:   "title 2",
            content: "content 2"
        },
    }
%}
```

I can reference any specific array element in other markup.  E.g., this works as intended

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <h1>{{ test.sec1.title }}</h1>
        <div>
            <p>{{ test.sec1.content }}</p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now I want to loop/repeat the block over a count of n.  But trying this,

```
<ul>
{% for i in 1..5 %}
    <li>
        <h1>{{ test.sec{{ i }}.title }}</h1>
        <div>
            <p>{{ test.sec{{ i }}.content }}</p>
        </div>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

fires an error

```
Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "{" ("end of print statement" expected) in default/index.html.twig at line 67.
500 Internal Server Error - Twig_Error_Syntax
```

I've been working with variations of these

```
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#iterating-over-keys
```

but can't get anything to work yet.

What's the right way to loop this list over the secN's in the key-value array?

Answer (score 2):

The reason why your script does not work is that you cannot compose an object-property accessor like this.

What you probably need is [iterating over a subset](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#iterating-over-a-subset):

> ```
> {% for sec in test|slice(0, 5) %}
>     {{ sec.title }}
> {% endfor %}
> ```

Or, if you do indeed need access to the key: [iteration over key and value](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#iterating-over-keys-and-values):

> ```
> {% for key, sec in test %}
>     {{ sec.title }}
>     {{key}}
> {% endfor %}
> ```

If you need to slice while still accessing the key, you could combine the latter with a check to the [loop variables](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable):

> ```
> {% for key, sec in test %}
>     {% if loop.index0 < 5 %}
>         {{ sec.title }}
>         {{key}}
>     {% endif %}
> {% endfor %}
> ```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks!  More interesting was learning about 'slice'!  Useful ...

Answer (score 0):

```
       {% for key, item in content.field_invoice_no if key|first != '#' %} 
<tr>
       <td>{{ item }}</td>
       <td> {{ content.field_invoice_date[key] }}      </td>
</tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

Iterating over key-value arrays in Twig

for reference entity code below

```
 {% for  key, item1 in node.field_quotation.entity.field_product  %} 
     <tr>
        <td>{{ loop.index }}</td>
        <td>{{ item1.entity.body.value |raw }}</td>
         <td> {{ item1.entity.field_product_unit_required.value }}</td>
         <td>{{ item1.entity.field_hsn_code.value }}</td>
        <td>{{item1.entity.field_pro.number|number_format(2, '.', ',')}}</td>
 {% endfor %}        
      </tr>
```